# Flex barChart and XML Data

Tags: xml, apache-flex

```
    <Projectlist>
    <Project>
    <ProjectName>Alcoswitch - ToggleSwitches
    </ProjectName>
    <ProjectStatusname>Planning</ProjectStatusname>
    </Project>
    <Project>
    <ProjectName>
    Transverse Wedge</ProjectName>
    <ProjectStatusname>Canceled</ProjectStatusname>
    </Project>
    <Project>
    <ProjectName>High Speed Pluggable I/O</ProjectName>
    <ProjectStatusname>In-Progress</ProjectStatusname>
    </Project>
    <Project>
    <ProjectName>"High Speed Pluggable I/O - Product Breakouts:</ProjectName>
    <ProjectStatusname>In-Progress</ProjectStatusname>
    </Project>
    <Project>
    <ProjectName>Circular Plastic Connector (CPC)</ProjectName>
    <ProjectStatusname>In-Progress</ProjectStatusname>
    </Project>
    </Projectlist>
```

This is my XML data i am recieving, how can i show this in a bar chart.

```
<mx:BarChart id="barChart"
             showDataTips="true" dataProvider="{ProjectStateInfo}"

             width="100%"
             height="100%">
             <mx:horizontalAxis>
                 <mx:CategoryAxis categoryField="ProjectStatusname"/>
             </mx:horizontalAxis>
        <mx:verticalAxis>
            <mx:CategoryAxis categoryField="ProjectName"/>
        </mx:verticalAxis>
        <mx:series>
            <mx:BarSeries id="barSeries" visible="true"
                    yField="ProjectName"
                    xField="ProjectStatusname"
                    displayName="ProjectStatusname"
                     />


        </mx:series>
    </mx:BarChart>
```

My X-Axis shows muliple values of In-Progress, but i just need one. Is it possible to represent such relationship using BarChart. Any other Flex chart is Advisable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build an array (or another data structure) containing all the project status names, and use it for the horizontal axis. you need that to eliminate the duplicates.

```
var array:Array = ["Planning","Canceled","In-Progress"];

<mx:BarChart id="barChart"
         showDataTips="true" dataProvider="{xml.Project}"
         width="100%"
         height="100%">
         <mx:horizontalAxis>
             <mx:CategoryAxis dataProvider="{array}"/>
         </mx:horizontalAxis>
         <mx:verticalAxis>
            <mx:CategoryAxis dataProvider="{xml.Project}" categoryField="ProjectName"/>
         </mx:verticalAxis>
         <mx:series>
            <mx:BarSeries id="barSeries" visible="true"
                yField="ProjectName"
                xField="ProjectStatusname"
                displayName="ProjectStatusname"
                 />
         </mx:series>           
</mx:BarChart>
```